# Get index path of CoreData one-to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uitableview

I'd expect to have something like `[_contact.phones objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`; available to me. Where _`contact` is my core data object and phones is a to many relationship from the contact. Yet this is not available to me. I'm trying to do this in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation (where phones would be its own section) yet I can't figure out how to do this without adding phones to an external array at the time of loading then using that instead.

Could someone give me some advice as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core data to-many relationships use `NSSet`.  If you check "ordered" in XCode it will become an `NSOrderedSet` which has an `objectAtIndex` method.

You would not want to use the unordered set because even if you got an array of objects with NSSet's `allObjects` method, the ordering is not necessarily the same every time you call it.

See for instance this answer:
[Ordered Sets and Core Data (NSOrderedSet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217925/ordered-sets-and-core-data-nsorderedset)

`objectAtIndexPath` would make sense if the data structure were a tree and not an array.

Comment: I had given up and started doing it with an array. Thankfully I didn't get that far into it. Thanks from a fellow Seattleite.